# Detailed instructions how to make a VS2022 C++ app;ication working on another computer without VS2022

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2022

I have developed an application in VS2022 C++ and want to use it on another computer without VS2022.
I compiled the C++ program in the release mode.
Is there detailed step-by-step instruction on what to do next?

Google tells that a problem may be with the redistributables.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/deployment-in-visual-cpp?view=msvc-170

Comment: @Hans Passant: Thank you, so I need to create my application installer.

Comment: You also need to understand what dependencies you have, based on the build options and libraries your application was built with. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/understanding-the-dependencies-of-a-visual-cpp-application?view=msvc-170 for details

Comment: On computers without VS2022, you will most likely need to install the VS2022 redistributable, here you can find the [Latest Redistributables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170) If your app is x64 you would need to install `vc_redist.x64.exe` file.

Answer (score 1):

Detailed step-by-step instruction is here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/deploying-visual-cpp-application-by-using-the-vcpp-redistributable-package?view=msvc-170

See also:

https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-make-an-exe-installation-file/

I have successfully deployed my application on another computer.